# Electron - JavaScript Error Adding Tray Icon to Windows PC

Tags: javascript, electron

I am running into this error while trying to learn Electron and show an Icon in the tray of a windows computer. Does anyone know what may be causing this error?

> A JavaScript error occurred in the main process.
>
> Uncaught Exception: Type Error: Insufficient number of arguments.
>
> at App.app.on
> (C:\Users\davidb\Desktop\ElectronCode\boilerplates\tasky\index.js:18:3)
>
> at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
> at App.emit (events.js:191:7)

```
const path = require('path');
const electron = require('electron');

const { app, BrowserWindow, Tray } = electron;

let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 500,
    width: 300,
    frame: false,
    resizable: false
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/src/index.html`);

  const iconName = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'windows-icon.png' : 'iconTemplate.png';
  const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, `./src/assets/${iconName}`);
  new Tray(iconPath);
});
```

Comment: The error seems to occur when you don't pass anything into `new Tray()`, so `iconPath` might be undefined.

Comment: so weird when i click the x on the error it still loads and works fine. I dont get it lol